# Convert function with date formatted as text

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, date, sqlserver, convert

I have a DE1 with field named 'DATE_A' with datatype text. This field contains records that are formatted like this: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm`.
Using sql query activity I should retrieve records with field `DATE_A = TODAY DATE` in order to populate another DE2 with field named 'DATE_B' with datatype text. I have tried to use this WHERE Condition:

```
DATE_A = convert(varchar, getdate(), 23)
```

but query returns zero records because in DE1 the field DATE_A have `hh:mm`.
Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a `left()` function (or similar) that you can use to just grab the first 10 characters of the field before using getdate()?

Comment: convert/cast the date_a field also  example cast(date_a as date)

Comment: I have solved using this condition: WHERE substring(DATE_A,1,10) = convert(varchar, getdate(), 23). In this manner, I exclude hh and mm and I retrieve records with current date

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but likely doing as @EazyE said and casting as date would be the more performant and easier solution. Something like: `WHERE CAST(date_a as date)  = CAST(getDate() as date)`